# JUnit using HyperSQL to test DAO classes

Tags: java, unit-testing

I did some research on how to test my DAO layer using HyperSQL and I found this question: **https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/219362/how-to-test-the-data-access-layer**

How do I import DBConnection because I tried using hypersql jar and it did not work. In the question from the link I saw this `db.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:src/test/resources/testData;shutdown=true;` but I do not know how to use it.

Comment: How are you connecting to your live database?  Hibernate?  Plain old JDBC?  Are you using Spring?  What you've got there is the connection string, so it needs to replace the live connection string when you're running unit tests.

Comment: @AndyN I am using JDBC and Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JDBC and Spring, in your application you'd be creating a `DataSource` object, and using that object to create a `JdbcTemplate` object, which is what you're using to run your JDBC queries.  Similar to [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_jdbc_example.htm) example.  So in order to use the HSql database, you'd need to change the values used to setup the `DataSource` bean but only for your unit tests.

Depending on how you're using Spring (annotations, xml config), there's a few ways of doing it. You'll need to create a new configuration bean, or configuration xml file, and then reference it in your unit tests.

For XML, copy over your spring context xml file, and change the `DataSource` values to something like:

```
<bean id="dataSource" 
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:src/test/resources/testData;shutdown=true;"/>
  <property name="username" value="SA"/>
  <property name="password" value=""/>
```

You'll then need to reference this new context config in your unit test.  Something like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
// ApplicationContext will be loaded from "classpath:/test-config.xml"
@ContextConfiguration("/test-config.xml")
public class DAOTests {
    @Autowired
    private DatabaseDAO dao;
}
```

With annotations, you'll need to make a new configuration class (you should have one already, a class annotated with `@Configuration`) and return the appropriate `DataSource`.  Something like this:

```
@Bean
public DataSource hsqlDataSource(){
    return DataSourceBuilder
        .create()
        .driverClassName("org.hsql.jdbcDriver")
        .url("jdbc:hsqldb:file:src/test/resources/testData;shutdown=true;")
        .username("SA")
        .password("");
        .build();
}
```

You can setup a profile for your configuration (using `@Profile("test")` annotation), and then specify which profile you want to use in your unit test (`@ActiveProfiles("test")`). More information [here](https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles).

Alternatively, you could use the Spring EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder if you're just trying to do a simple DAO Test.  There's a tutorial [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-embedded-database-examples/).  It sets you up with a HSql in memory database (as opposed to a file based one), which is very convenient for setting up / tearing down.  Just add the bean to your configuration class, and your DAO should pick it up if Spring is injecting the `DataSource` for you.  Example below taken from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-embedded-database-examples/)

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {

    // no need shutdown, EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryBean will take care of this
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
        .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
        .addScript("db/setup_script.sql")
        .build();
}
```

There's a bit to Spring configuration management.  I haven't covered it in much detail in this answer, but look up a few examples and it will start to make sense.

Comment: **http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-embedded-database-examples/** this here is tutorial for integration test. I am tryign to make unit test.

Comment: With a HSql database communicating with your DAO?  That's a small integration test.  If you're doing a unit test of your DAO, you'd just mock your JDBCTemplate, or DataSource, and you wouldn't need to work out where your database URL is defined.

Comment: Will you please give me an example how to do that ? if you agree, use the example from the link.

Comment: I've added in an embedded database example.  But I would not recommend mocking out the DataSource with just a mock.  I don't feel it accomplishes a whole lot.  I'd recommend you use HSql (or similar small database) in your DAO "unit testing".

Comment: What is the difference between HSql and DBUnit and is it correct to use DBUnit instead HSql.

Comment: That's a whole new question.  I can't say I've used DBUnit.  There's some info on dbunit and spring here though: https://springtestdbunit.github.io/spring-test-dbunit/

Comment: I have one last question... When i am using HSql what model i have to made ? The model which is in the real code or just some model for testing ?

Comment: I use the same config of tables and mappings for test as I do for prod, but obviously with any SQL implementation specific changes (you'll need to look up the differences between HSQL and your chosen prod database implementation, that's another large question).  I then fill test with test data.